# how to select a column name based on slug string in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

im creating landing pages based on a created :slug

for example www.mysite.com/stores/new-york  and new-york is a created slug in the back-end(admin)

so if i visit the the url i want to see a list of all the stores in new-york.

i have a table called landing_pages with a column named slug and in that column are all names stored for the pages i want to generate. like new-york, Washington, Miami. etc

and i have a table stores whit a column store and city

how can i generate a list with all the stores from the given slug name.

hope someone can help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your caps key appears to be broken. Using proper grammar, capitalization and formatting helps us read what you've written. When we can read it easily, we're more inclined to help you, so, by putting in a bit more effort you increase your chance of getting answers. Stack Overflow is like an online resource book, and, while we often will help you by editing to improve a question, we also expect you to make an attempt to do things to match the SO style.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). This stuff is pretty simple

```
# routes.rb
get 'stores/:slug', to: 'stores#landing_page'
```

Now in your controller

```
# stores_controller.rb

def landing_page
  # something like this
  @stores = Store.where(city: params[:slug])

  # any other assignments
  # ...
end
```

Comment: hi thanks for you're answer!

I had already come so far, only i can not list the stores who has the same city as the slug name. 

for example i have 2 tables one named landing_page with a column slug
and one table store with a column city. 
and when my slug is new-york i want all the stores with the city new-york
from the table store list on my url www.mysite.com/stores/newyork
is that possible??

thanks again.
asked from a newbie in rails who loved to learn it :)

Comment: If you want to match the `city` column on your `stores` table, then you will need to do `Store.where(city: params[:slug])`